# Class Carbon\Carbon contains 2 abstract methods

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with Carbon, i don't know how fix this. I'm using Laravel 5.8.

Error:

> Class Carbon\Carbon contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (DateTimeInterface::main\vendor\composer, DateTimeInterface::main\vendor\composer)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLF5e.png)

Comment: what version of php are you running this on?

Comment: Hello, PHP 7.1.9

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after my computer was rebooted automatically for an update: *Class Carbon\Carbon contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Carbon\CarbonInterface::toAtomString)*

I thought some files got corrupted or something because everything was fine the day before and the code was untouched.

Long story short, the fix was clearing Laravel's cache :

```
php artisan cache:clear
```